# How to import and render svg file based on given name from variable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

### Problem

I have a large array of categories and a variable whose value is one of the categories, lets say

```
const categories = ['a1', 'a2', ..., 'a200'];
const category = 'a57';
```

I have a svg file corresponding to each category name: 'a1.svg', 'a2.svg', ..., 'a200.svg'

My problem is that, I need to render only one svg file, based on a variable that comes from categories array and I can't render it as image, because I need to be able to change it's fill/stroke value.

```
<img src={`./images/${category}.svg} />
```

I tried to import all the svgs like this

```
import {ReactComponent as a1} from './images/ai.svg';
```

and put all those imports in array. But when I did it this way, I had an array of objects like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOF4h.png).
In theory I could work with that, but some of my categories had spaces and other symbols and I couldn't use *.render.name* value since you can't import like this *{ReactComponent as martial arts}*. It's also uncomfortable cause I need to do a lot of imports instead of doing something like

```
const images = categories.map(category => {
  return {
    name: category,
    svg: require(`./images/${category}.svg`
  }
})
```

I also tried to make an array of objects which would look like this

```
const images = [ {name: 'a1', svg: a1}, {name: 'a2', svg: a2} ];
```

and render it as

```
{images.find(img => img.name === category).svg}
```

but I couldn't cause it would give me this error

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

### Goal

Render only one svg component based on the category variable that's value could be anything from the categories array. Also, how to correctly import those svgs in a way that would allow me to easily render the svg and change its fill/stroke value in CSS.

Something similiar to making an import like this to work

```
import {ReactComponent as imageCategory} from `./images/${category}.svg`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
> use an array instead.

This occurs because you are not rendering the component, you are just getting the component instance:

```
const Svg = images.find(img => img.name === category).svg //--> component instance

return <Svg /> //--> render it

//--> **Note:** this just an example it won't work because it won't find the module.
```

#### To make it work

If you are using `Webpack`, you can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext):

```
const svgDir = require.context("!@svgr/webpack!./images");

const images = categories.map(category => {
  return {
    name: category,
    svg: svgDir(`./${category}.svg`).default
  }
});
```

then:

```
 const renderImgByCategory = (category) => {
     const Svg = images.find(img => img.name === category).svg;
     return <Svg/>
 }
```

JSX:

```
{renderImgByCategory(category)}
```